# XTerm not closing using -e option

Tags: xterm

I have an tcl script running in MWM and it starts xterm terminals with:

```
 .menu.utils.m add command -label {Xterm} -command {
        exec xterm -sb -T "Xterm" -sl 10000 -e su - int &
  }
```

Doing this, the terminals can't be closed using Alt+F4 or the Menu bar. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing in the end was finding the focused window and xkilling it in the following way:

```
 f.exec "xkill -id `xdpyinfo | grep focus | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d ','`"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `xkill`?  That will destroy the window, though it will leave behind the `su` process and it's children.  You can try to Ctrl-C in the `xterm` to kill the process.  Or if it's actually an `xterm` process (and not `gnome-terminal` or some such) you can Ctrl-Left-Click and send a KILL (or other) signals to the child process.

**UPDATE**
I think you could add something like this to your `.mwmrc`:

```
Keys MyKeyBindings
{
    Alt Shift<Key>F4     window   f.exec "xkill -id <WM_CLIENT_LEADER>"
}
```

The reason that `f.kill` and `Close` in `fvwm` doesn't close an `xterm -e su -` is because the `xterm` can't end the sub-process.  So to get the Window Manager to end the `xterm` it needs to be destroyed and not politely asked to close.

Comment: The problem ist not to kill the window. I can type exit into the terminal and the window is gone. But I need Alt+F4 and the "close" entry in the menu to work

Comment: @AlexanderStolz Can you update your question with the relevant parts of you mwmrc?

Comment: What do you mean by relevant parts?

Comment: When I use this in my .mwmrc it prompts me to select a window to kill which I don't want